# Three.js and Django?

Tags: javascript, django, three.js

somebody knows if can i upload a Three.js project to Django?
i did a project to upload jpg and png images in Django, but i have another project in three.js to use .OBJ images, but now i neet to include my Three.js project to my Django project but i don't know how and if its posible to do it... Thank u so much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2WRJ.png)

> `files to Django project`

[files to Three.js project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRmpb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use both Django and Three.js together.
Three.js is a library run on the client-side and so needs to be included with the static files for Django.

From the directory structures, you have included in your question the index.html file would become a Django template. It's not clear what elements of your Three.js project you want to make dynamic or vice versa.
The rest of the Three.js folder structure could then be moved to a static folder.
You will probably need to update the path structure of the imports in the Three.js scripts to include `/static/original_folder/file.type`